# Angular 5, using a component in a sub-module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I am getting an error I cannot seem to remedy, when I sub-divided my app for lazy loading efficiencies
and and using a sub-router for `"child"`,
 I need to use a component that is used in the main app.

But I am getting **This below error message**

> Type AccountInfoComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules

My app structure looks like this

```
app
|--components
    |--accountInfo
        |--accountInfo.component.ts
    |--user
        |--user.component.ts
|--modules
    |--child
        |--child.component.ts
        |--child.module.ts
        |--child.routing.module.ts
|--app.module.ts
|--app.routing.module.ts
```

Where AccountInfoComponent is declaired in the main module (it is not imported to the main router, it is called via it's selector...)

So I moved my "child" component into its own module, complete with a router (for children) and lazy loading

My `"Child.router"` looks like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import { ChildProfileComponent } from './child.profile.component';

import { AccountInfoComponent } from '../../components/accountinfo/accountinfo.component';

const childRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: ChildComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ChildProfileComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'account',
                component: AccountInfoComponent 
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild( childRoutes )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule {}
```

The main `app.module` declairs `AccountInfoComponent` because it is used in user.component.

I have tried importing `AccountInfoComponent` into the child router, I have tried exporting it from the main module.

> QUESTION: How do I use a component in more than one module? the main app and a nested module?

Comment: You want to factor it into another module that you then reference in both.

Comment: I was afraid of that - I've got a bunch of components, that are going to have to be their own modules...Is this common?

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately fairly common. `NgModule` is a badly-designed abstraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you cannot declare a component in more than one module

You can create a shared module that will contain the components that you want to reuse in more than one module.

This shared module in your example could declare and export the `AccountInfoComponent`, and other components that you'll need to reuse in different modules.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#sharedmodule

You can declare multiple components in your shared module, or you can create one module per component and import them selectively, which is what angular material does (`MatButtonModule`, `MatCheckboxModule`, ...)