# How to add a component in sub module instead of AppModule?

Tags: angular

Reference Answer: [Angular 5, using a component in a sub-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827777/angular-5-using-a-component-in-a-sub-module) but it didn't help my problem.

I have a sub-module `PagesModule` under `AppModule`. I imported a component in the `PagesModule` as follow:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ECommerceModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdvertisementComponent,
  ],
  providers: [ModuleService],
})
```

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-advertisement',
  templateUrl: './advertisement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./advertisement.component.scss']
})
export class AdvertisementComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: NbAuthJWTInterceptor, multi: true},
    AuthGuard,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

AppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

I am using the `AdvertismenetComponent` selector in the `ECommerceComponent` template which is added in the `ECommerceModule`, which is in the `PagesModules`.

But I get the following error:

> 'ngx-advertisement' is not a known element:

Comment: I think you should show the module structure of your application, and indicate in which module the component is declared, and in which module you are trying to use it. That would help us to help you.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I added the structure for the modules. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better solution would be to have shared module.

**AdvertisementModule**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AdvertisementComponent} from './advertisement.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [
    AdvertisementComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    AdvertisementComponent,
  ],
})

export class AdvertisementModule {
}
```

**And import it in other modules**

This solved two issues: having the component in two modules and unknown element problem.

This works best for lazy loading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a component outside his module, you also need to export it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ECommerceModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdvertisementComponent,
  ],
  exports: [AdvertisementComponent],
  providers: [ModuleService],
})
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Do you think it is using outside module? I have `EcommerceComponent` under `ECommerceModule` and the `ECommerceModule` is under `PagesModule`?

Comment: Did you import PagesModule into ECommerceModule?

Comment: It is other way round. The ECommerceModule is imported in PagesModule.

Comment: If, in a module (M1), you want to use a component (C) declared in another module (M2), you need to import M2 into M1. M2 must declare and export C.

Comment: core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'ECommerceModule'
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'ECommerceModule'